# How to pivot sql data, and squash results into non-null rows by Date per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, notnull

Not a good title to the post, but hopefully it'll catch some eyes.

I have a very complex situation in T-SQL that I am unable to accomplish. I'm hoping someone with expertise knows an elegant and fast solution so that my performance is not impacted. I'm dealing with *billions of rows*.

**PREFACE**

I have a table called **Customers** with a unique ID. Those customers have **Files**, Files have Properties, and each Property **Name** corresponds to a single **Value**.

**Tables:**

- Customers
- Files -
- Property - contains both Name and Value

The **Customer ID** is present in all of these tables, as are audit fields such as **UpdatedDtm** and **CreationDtm**.

**USE CASE**

I need to join all customers to their files (filtering for a few) and then tie every file to their properties (again filtering these). This is easy but results in lots of rows, one for each **customer x file x property**.

I know that the property names will never changes, and I want to return just a select few, so I used a pivot and resulted in a nice table, but it fell apart after I started doing more complex queries.

**THE PROBLEM**
First, the properties have a DateTime for when they were altered (**UpdatedDtm**), and I need to return everything altered from 1 hour of the creation date (**CreationDtm**) in the File table.

This results in me trimming down my list of potential properties, but now I have a table with an **RowNumber()** per ID and no good way to pivot and select the first one that isn't null and still preserve the number of columns for the table defnition. This is important because I'm using **Dynamic SQL** and placing it in an indexed temp table with a **Composite Key** on **CustomerID** and **FileName**.

**BEFORE PIVOT**

```
| UpdatedDtm | CustomerID | FileName   | Property | Value          |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | -------- | -------------- |
| 1/1/2015   | 1          | FileOne    | Size     | NULL           |
| 1/1/2015   | 1          | FileOne    | Format   | JPG            |
| 1/7/2015   | 1          | FileOne    | Size     | 88KB           |
| 1/7/2015   | 1          | FileOne    | Format   | JPG            |
| 1/7/2015   | 1          | FileOne    | Comment  | NULL           |
| 1/11/2015  | 1          | FileOne    | Comment  | NULL           |
| 1/1/2015   | 1          | FileTwo    | Size     | 91KB           |
| 1/1/2015   | 1          | FileTwo    | Format   | PNG            |
| 1/11/2015  | 1          | FileTwo    | Comment  | NULL           |
| 1/2/2015   | 2          | FileThree  | Size     | 74KB           |
| 1/2/2015   | 2          | FileThree  | Format   | XLS            |
| 1/2/2015   | 2          | FileThree  | State    | Open           |
| 1/7/2015   | 2          | FileThree  | State    | Closed         |
| 1/10/2015  | 2          | FileThree  | Comment  | NULL           |
| 1/1/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 2KB            |
| 1/2/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 10KB           |
| 1/3/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 13KB           |
| 1/4/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 21KB           |
| 1/5/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 27KB           |
| 1/6/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 32KB           |
| 1/7/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 39KB           |
| 1/8/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Size     | 44KB           |
| 1/1/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Format   | TXT            |
| 1/1/2015   | 3          | FileFour   | Comment  | NULL           |
```

Please don't ask me why the database is setup this way or to change the schema. That is set in stone and out of my control. I need to be able to solve the use case as described.

**AFTER PIVOT (Expectation)**

```
| CustomerID | FileName   | Size | Format | State  | Comment |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---- | ------ | ------ | ------- |
| 1          | FileOne    | 88KB | JPG    | NULL   | NULL    |
| 1          | FileTwo    | 91KB | PNG    | NULL   | NULL    |
| 2          | FileThree  | 74KB | XLS    | Closed | NULL    |
| 3          | FileFour   | 44KB | TXT    | NULL   | NULL    |
```

I have included some NULL values and missing values to showcase that I need to preserve the same columnar properties regardless of them having data, but I also need to squash the data by the the first non-null value within my date range.

**CODE (My attempt)**

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#FilesQuery') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FilesQuery;
CREATE TABLE #FilesQuery (
    SeqNum          int,
    CustomerID      numeric(16,0),
    FileName        varchar(64),
    PropertyName    varchar(64),
    PropertyValue   varchar(64)
)
INSERT INTO #FilesQuery
SELECT
     CASE WHEN P.[Value] IS NOT NULL
          THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by C.CustomerID order by UpdatedDtm)
          ELSE 0
     END as SeqNum,
     C.CustomerID
    ,F.Name  as FileName
    ,P.Name  as PropertyName
    ,P.Value as PropertyValue

FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Files F ON F.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Properties P
    ON P.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    AND P.FileID = F.FileID

WHERE F.FileName IN ('FileOne','FileTwo','FileThree','FileFour')
    AND P.Name IN ('Size','Format','State','Comment')

--PIVOT
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(PropertyName)
       FROM #FilesQuery fq
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

DECLARE @dynSql AS nvarchar(MAX)
SET @dynSql = '
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            fq.CustomerID,
            fq.FileName,
            fq.PropertyName,
            fq.PropertyValue
        FROM #FilesQuery fq
    ) SRC
    PIVOT (
        Max([PropertyValue])
        FOR PropertyName IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) PVT
'

IF Object_id('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results;
CREATE TABLE #Results (
    CustomerID      varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    FileName        varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    FileSize        varchar(64) NULL,
    FileFormat      varchar(64) NULL,
    FileState       varchar(64) NULL,
    FileComment     varchar(64) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_CustDoc PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID,FileName)
)
INSERT INTO #Results EXEC @dynSql;
```

I'm sorry this code isn't complete, it is the working section I have. The other tries I made resulted in bad data pulls.

I tried using SeqNum and a combination of case statements to try and select the first non-null value for each row so that the data was all on one line, but it ended up being more like.

```
FileOne NULL NULL Open NULL
FileOne NULL JPG  NULL NULL
```

and so on...

I've been struggling on solving this special case for awhile and am about to scrap and it do something procedural with looping, but that would kill my query time and performance.

Anyone have a good solution? Am I over-thinking things?

Comment: Hm, have you tried reducing the dataset to only the relevant rows by selecting just the latest (highest UpdatedDtm) for each file/property combo before doing the `PIVOT`? That way the `PIVOT` should already be able to give you directly the output you are looking for, no? Sorry, I can't test TSQL at the moment...

Comment: Yes, I will be chunking the data into bins, such as 1 hour ago, 2 hours, etc. but the use case is centered around selecting the first non-null value per column and still preserving all columns, as with a cross join allowing nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should filter your data before you `PIVOT` and you will get your desired results. Here is a cte version to show you the steps of how to get what you want.

```
;WITH cteDefineRowPrecedence AS (
    SELECT *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId, FileName, Property ORDER BY
          CASE WHEN Value IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
          ,UpdatedDtm DESC) as RowNum
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteDesiredRwows AS (
    SELECT
       CustomerId
       ,FileName
       ,Property
       ,Value
    FROM
       cteDefineRowPrecedence t
    WHERE
       t.RowNum = 1
       AND t.Value IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteDesiredRwows t
    PIVOT (
       MAX(Value)
       FOR Property IN (Size,[Format],[State],Comment)
    ) p
ORDER BY
    CustomerId
    ,FileName
```

And here is a nested query version that will make it easier to embed/put in your dynamic sql....

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT CustomerId, FileName, Property, Value
       FROM
          (SELECT *
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId, FileName, Property ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN Value IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                ,UpdatedDtm DESC) as RowNum
          FROM
             @Table) r
       WHERE
          r.RowNum = 1
          AND r.Value IS NOT NULL
    ) t
    PIVOT (
       MAX(Value)
       FOR Property IN (Size,[Format],[State],Comment)
    ) p
ORDER BY
    CustomerId
    ,FileName
```

Comment: I'm new to CTEs, but I tried your query and It keeps telling me "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2    Invalid column name 'Property'." Any ideas?

Comment: Your documentation shows Property as the column name or did I get that wrong?  The error means it can't find a column by that name in your table.  Also perhaps you misspelled it somewhere if you where trying to merge what I wrote with your queries?

Comment: I double-checked and checked again, maybe I needed to close my session and start a new query. My cache might have preserved a bad table definition. EDIT: Just tried, same deal. The temp table I'm pulling from has the correctly named column in Select, so I have no idea why dynSql can't use the alias.

Comment: ctrl + shift + r will update your auto complete/ intellisense

Comment: Nested inner select 'r' works. Subquery 't' works. So I thought to myself, the only other thing left is Order By and for some reason I accidentally has Property instead of FileName as my order by. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: great glad it worked for you.  Please do accept my answer if you are moving forward with it thanks!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a WHERE condition inside the CTE definition to restrict the date/time range to what you want.

```
   WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CustomerID
        , FileName
        , Property
        , Value
    FROM
        <table_name>
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM
        CTE
        PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR Property IN( 'Size', 'Format', 'State', 'Comment')) p
```

Comment: I'm unable to get a where statement in the CTE to grab a range of dates and take the youngest or oldest first non-null value inside of them. This is a quick and dirty solution that leans on Max() for the outcome and I'd like to get away from that.

Comment: The Max() operator is for the pivot, not to filter the outcome. Pivot always require an aggregation function and in this case, Max() is the obvious choice. The key thing is that you'll need to make sure that there is a unique combination of <CustomerID, FileName, Property> returned from the CTE.